# About using functions in view in Backbone Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

What I want to do is this:

```
events : {
    "click" : "doSomething"
},

doSomething(event) : function() {
    this.doSomeFurtherAction1();
    this.doSomeFurtherAction2();

},

doSomeFutherAction1: function() {
    //some actions
},

doSomeFutherAction2: function() {
    //some actions
}
```

However; my secondary functions are not attached to the view as I was expecting. Is there a way of doing this other than putting the code in the app or controller?

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'secondary fns not attached to the view'? Do you mean `this.doSomethingFurtherAction1` is undefined in that context?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I mean in doSomething() I have no visibility of doSomeFutherAction1(). I had assumed it would be just on 'this' i.e. the view, but it is not. I think the solution may be to just define doSomeFurtherAction1 inside doSomething and then call it. I'm just wondering if there is another way to attach a function to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
doSomething(event) : function() {
  this.doSomeFurtherAction1();
  this.doSomeFurtherAction2();
},
```

Should Be:

```
doSomething: function(event) {
  this.doSomeFurtherAction1();
  this.doSomeFurtherAction2();
},
```

This should solve your problem.

You might want to bind all your function to the view for other use cases:

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That works. It seems to bind all the methods it finds in the scope. (The wrongly placed 'event' was a typo here not in the code) ( (:- ).

Comment: @JustinWyllie it happens ;) , glad to help